# View event details in Firebase

Tags: firebase, events, firebase-analytics

I am sending app usage analytics events to Fabric and Firebase. Together with the event, I am also sending another value (an example event type is font_selection and the value I pass is which font the user selects - this is a number that tells me which font was used). I was using Fabric events and I could see which fonts were being used more or less when I selected the font_selection event (I could see numbers for each different font).

Since the Fabric functionality is being moved to Firebase, I started checking the Analytics section in Firebase. Unfortunately I cannot find the above information in Firebase > Analytics > Events. I can see the event, font_selection but when I click on it I do not get the additional information I used to get in Fabric. Is there something I am missing or has this additional information been removed from Firebase?

Comment: After looking some more into Firebase events I saw that you can Edit parameter reporting for each event (click the 3 dots at the right of the event for the Edit option). You are then presented with a list of available parameters and you can choose the ones you want to track. However it looks like there is a limit of 5 different parameter values. In addition, it looks like data for these parameters starts getting updated after you define them - this means that if you define report params for an event today, you lose all past data (from start until today). Any comments on this?

Comment: on same page at bottom you can see VIEW button to view raw events in BigQuery you can find your event details there

Comment: I know about BigQuery but it is not free. Do you have any idea or numbers about the charges based on a given number of events per day?

Answer (score 2):

This is still an issue for me. Here is how I'm sending the event into Firebase:

```
protected void Report(string id, Severity severity, string message = null, Exception exception = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var processedId = id ?? severity.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            values.Add("severity", severity.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
            {
                values.Add("message", message);
            }

            if (exception != null)
            {
                values.Add("exception", exception.Message);
                values.Add("trace", exception.StackTrace);
            }

            SendEvent(values, processedId);
        }
        catch
        {
            // do nothing.
        }
    }

protected override void SendEvent(Dictionary<string, string> eventData, string id)
    {
        var firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(Android.App.Application.Context);
        var bundle = new Android.OS.Bundle();

        foreach(var pair in eventData)
        {
            bundle.PutString(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        firebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(id, bundle);
    }
```

During runtime, I call this successfully and I can see these event popping up in Firebase console:

[image]

**But how do I display the rest of the properties that I have bundled with it?** Here is what the console shows me in events:

[image]

I feel like I must be using it wrong or something. There is no UI to shows me a simple chronologically sorted table with events as they came in with properties they came with. I frankly don't understand what good is this tool to me.